# Selenium - Using wildcards in xpath

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

Is there 1 xpath expression that can cover all below:

```
//center/b[contains(string(), 'New password')]
//center/h3[contains(string(), 'Renaming user ID')]
//h3/center[contains(string(), 'Updating Email to')]
//h3/center[contains(string(), 'Retrieving Azure status')]
```

This is what I have:

```
public String getMessage(String message) {
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(string(), '" + message + "')]")).getText();
}
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Do you have an efficiency problem? With a setup like Selenium, I cannot imagine that XPath performance, of all things, is an issue.

Comment: I do have a DRY problem, as each expression has their own method. Took that part of the question out, I just want 1 expression that covers all 4 cases. The string can be passed as an arg to the method.

Comment: The easiest way would be to join them with the union operator `|`.

Comment: Added what I came up with but not too happy with it (though it works). If you can post an answer with the `|` operator, I would like to study it. Just need 1 working example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can combine them with `or` and `|`.

Shortened for the sake of legibility:

```
//path/one[contains(., 'A') or contains(., 'B')]|//path/two[contains(., 'C') or contains(., 'D')]
```

Be aware that this *will* give you multiple results if it can (like any XPath that is not specifically restricted to single-node results).

Comment: What would the `.` mean in `contains()?`

Comment: It's the current node, i.e. the node that the `[predicate]` works on. That's XPath 101, I can only recommend taking half an hour to go over a tutorial.